# Joomla mkdir() error

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, virtuemart, images, file-permissions

I have a problem with the [Virtuemart Color Swatch plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/color-swatch-for-virtuemart/) for Joomla 3.
When I add thumbnails to the product, in the admin panel, I get this error:

> Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in `/var/www/sitefolder/public_html/domain.com/plugins/vmcustom/color_swatch/color_swatch.php` on line 66

Here's the code from line 66:

```
$thumb_folder = $folder;
if (!is_dir(JPATH_SITE .'/'. $thumb_folder)) {
    mkdir(JPATH_SITE .'/'. $thumb_folder, 0777);
}
```

This custom field appears on the site, but without a photo (in the admin panel thumbnails are loaded).

I think this problem appears because the path to the thumbnails on line 66 is wrong.  The path to thumbnails is:

```
/images/stories/virtuemart/color_swatch/images/[here are the generated folders]
```

Also, if I give attribute `TRUE` after `0777`, the error disappear, but another error appears with "no rights" to directory.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].  Please also consider renaming your account to something more "human" and telling us about your Joomla background by editing your profile.

Comment: If it's a problem with a specific extension like this, it's usually better to raise the question on the support forum of the extension. I suggest you try that.